# grub rescue after uninstalling Ubuntu on EFI system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After I uninstalled Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 from my Notebook I started getting a grub rescue on every boot.

I completely formatted my HDD and tried to install Ubuntu again, but I got grub rescue even trying to boot from USB - I can't boot from it.

Now I've installed an Windows 8.1 on my Notebook.

I looked into my EFI partition and delete the Ubuntu EFI, but that didn't fix the problem.

I can't boot any live Linux OS.

I have an Acer Aspire ES1-311 c82s

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've probably deleted the wrong files from the ESP, or the right files from the wrong ESP. (Some computers have multiple ESPs, or multiple ESP-like partitions.) There are two ways to fix this:

- You can poke around looking for the right files or the right ESP. (This is best done if you understand your partitions. Something like the output of `sudo fdisk -l` in Ubuntu will help. On this forum, we understand tools for partitioning, and for mounting partitions, in Ubuntu better than in Windows.)
- Use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html), `efibootmgr`, or a similar tool to adjust the boot order so that Windows is first. (Some, but not all, EFIs let you do this in their setup utilities, too.)

The second option is likely to be easier, but you'll still have a bit of GRUB installed somewhere. This remnant of GRUB will likely cause no problems, but if you're compulsive about such things, you might prefer tracking it down and deleting it. OTOH, this approach is also riskier -- if you accidentally delete the wrong files, you could render you computer completely unbootable.